# Как правильно проверять (валидация) входящие параметры метода

Tags: c#, entity-framework, валидация

Часто интервьюеры отписывают мне, что в тестовых заданиях я не делаю валидацию.

Ранее для меня концепции `юнит-тестирование`, `валидация`, `try...catch` как-то было одно и тоже. И только за последний год я "освоил" юнит-тестирование и теперь не представляю свой код без тестов и кодирую через TDD (без фанатизма).

*try...catch для меня тоже немного темный лес, а именно: я так и не понял  когда именно его использовать.*

Но сегодня я хочу чтобы вы мне помогли разобраться с валидацией.

Вот прямо сейчас пишу код, реализуя паттерн фабричный метод, где создается объект TResultDTO для передачи его AngularJS во View. Объект TResultDTO формируется на основе EF-сущности TestResult. И я пытаюсь организовать валидацию:

```
public TResultDTO FactoryMethod(TestResult entity)
{
    //Валидация
    if(entity != null)
    {
        var dto = new TResultDTO
        {
            ExamCode = entity.TestPlan.Test.NumberCode,
            ExamName = entity.TestPlan.Test.Name,
            ExamDate = entity.TestDate.ToShortDateString(),
            ParticipCode = entity.ParticipCode
        };
        return dto;
    }                             
}
```

---

### Вопрос

1. Ну во первых VS сейчас пишет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и что мне с этим делать? Я не вижу выхода, разве что в конце метода указать `return null`. Ну тогда вообще что-то непонятное выходит.

2. Достаточно ли проверить `entity` на null? Или в идеале необходимо проверить его свойства (`entity.TestPlan.Test.NumberCode`, `entity.TestPlan.Test.Name` ...) , непосредственно к значениям которых обращается метод?

---

Я также понимаю, что наверника нет каких-то готовых формул и много (возможно) будет зависит от предметной области. Единственно, что я смог найти на этот счет в сети: коллега на форуме пишет, что входящие параметры **публичных** методов необходимо обязательно подвергать процессу валидации.

---

### Обновление

Прислушавшийся к ответам и комментариям делаю валидацию следующим образом:

```
namespace Monit95App.Models
{
    public class TResultDTOcreator : ITResultDTOcreator
    {
        public TResultDTO FactoryMethod(TestResult entity)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.TestPlan.Test.NumberCode))
                throw new ArgumentException("Property cannot be null or empty", nameof(entity.TestPlan.Test.NumberCode));
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.TestPlan.Test.Name))
                throw new ArgumentException("Property cannot be null or empty", nameof(entity.TestPlan.Test.Name));
            if (entity.TestPlan.TestDate == null || entity.TestPlan.TestDate == DateTime.MinValue)
                throw new ArgumentException("Property cannot be null or empty", nameof(entity.TestPlan.TestDate));
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.ParticipCode))
                throw new ArgumentException("Property cannot be null or empty", nameof(entity.ParticipCode));

            var dto = new TResultDTO
            {
                ExamCode = entity.TestPlan.Test.NumberCode,
                ExamName = entity.TestPlan.Test.Name,
                ExamDate = entity.TestDate.ToShortDateString(),
                ParticipCode = entity.ParticipCode
            };

            return dto;
        }
    }
}
```

Что теперь можете сказать коллеги?

*Ранее забыл отметить, что в проекте используется подход* `database first`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обо всём по порядку:

1. **Visual Studio всё пишет абсолютно правильно**

Ваш метод не `void`, но возвращает значение только если `entity != null`. А для случая `entity == null`? Конечно можно вернуть `null`, а можно открыть для себя [исключения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173160.aspx) или уже предложенный ранее паттерн NullObject.

2. **Всё зависит от задачи, а также того как и кем реализован класс объекта**

Не исключено, что все необходимые проверки уже реализованы внутри этого класса (если использовался подход code first) или на уровне БД. Но, если их нет или этот класс или БД создавали не Вы, лучше подстраховаться. К сожалению, на 2ю часть вопроса однозначно ответить очень сложно (она слишком "общая").

Comment: Класс TestResult это объект базы данных. В данном примере используется подход database first. Мне интересно сказанное Вами: `... все необходимые проверки уже реализованы внутри этого класса`. Что именно это означает?

Comment: @adamshakhabov, к сожалению, в исходном тексте вопроса про database first почему-то нет ни слова. Но даже в этом случае возможно реализовать валидацию на стороне C#. При этом не обязательно править код сгенерированный VS. Достаточно приделать к исходной сущности, например, "декоратор". Если, это конечно, оправдано.

Answer (score 4):

Валидация данных — очень простая штука. Это просто проверка на соответствие входных данных ожидаемому диапазону значений.

Например, если вам на вход даётся возраст человека, то он явно не может быть отрицательным. Ну и возраст в 4 миллиарда лет тоже как-то не выглядит правильным (хотя, здесь всё-таки зависит от задачи). Если вам даётся на вход дата начала работы и дата конца, то конец не может быть раньше начала.

Более простой случай — если вам приходит на вход объект, содержащий набор данных, вместо него не должен прийти `null`.

Более точно набор ограничений на входящие данные (то есть, критерий *правильности*) должен выдавать тот, кто написал функцию. Это обычно является частью документации.

Валидация данных и есть проверка того, что данные соответствуют ограничениям, и подходящая реакция на несоответствия. В C# принято выбрасывать исключение (обычно `ArgumentException` или производные от него), другие языки сообщают об ошибках по-другому (например, в Go возвращается объект типа `error`).

---

Для вашего случая, ваш код обращается к свойствам `entity`, `entity.TestPlan` и `entity.TestPlan.Test`. Поэтому для начала ваш код должен проверить `entity`:

```
if (entity == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
```

Далее, имеет ли право `entity.TestPlan` быть равно `null`? Если нет, вы должны учесть это в валидации:

```
if (entity.TestPlan == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity.TestPlan));
```

Если да, ваш код вылетит в случае, когда `entity.TestPlan == null`, и его нужно исправлять.

То же самое относится и к остальным свойствам, которые вы используете в коде.

---

Простой принцип: код не имеет права упасть с позорными исключениями наподобие `NullReferenceException` или там `IndexOutOfBoundException`. Если вы валидируете ваши входные данные, вы должны отловить все возможные источники проблем, и либо обработать их правильно в вашем коде, либо отвергнуть данные при валидации, выбросив исключение.

Answer (score 2):

Всё зависит от контекста, в котором используется ваш фабричный метод.

> разве что в конце метода указать `return null`

Если вы не хотите, что бы ваш фабричный метод возвращал `null` (и, как следствие, избежать последующей проверки на `null`) то рассмотрите вариант использования паттерна [NullObject](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_(%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

> Достаточно ли проверить entity на `null`?

Всё зависит от вашей задачи. Если для утверждения о том, что объект валиден, достаточно проверки на `null`, то да. Другой вопрос заключается в том, что должен ли фабричный метод заниматься валидацией объекта и не противоречит ли это [SRP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)?